# How Can I make async operations of my own with WinRT using IAsyncOperation interface?

Tags: asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I am developing a metro application and I want to create some async operations whose my own classes would implement.

I have found just examples of async using WinRT operations (e.g. CreateFileAsync). I do not find any intance where someone is creating a async method and consuming it.

Comment: Why don't you just try to implement the methods according to the (rather scarce) documentation?

Comment: Obviouslly, you do not have an in-depth knowledge of what is involved. This is what the documentation suggests.Even so thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. The documentation suggests asking at SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the same question in Microsoft forums and they gave me two replies. The first was:

> Hi Claudio,
>
> In the Developer Preview there isn't an easy way to create your own
>   async operations.  We are aware of this shortcoming and are trying to
>   solve it for the next pubic release.  In the meanwhile, you could
>   design your API as async and we will provide guidance on how to
>   convert sync to async.
>
> Thanks
>
> Raman Sharma, Visual C++

When I asked for the hard way to do this, another guy, someone responsible for PPL said me:

> We’re planning to do a refresh of the sample pack we released a few
>   weeks ago and add a few samples on creation of async operations. I
>   expect that it will happen in a couple of weeks or so. If you keep an
>   eye on our blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency, you’ll
>   be the first to know.
>
> As to how hard it is... The general-purpose solution that we’re
>   contemplating is about 1000 lines of C++ code making copious use of
>   template metaprogramming. Most of it will be in the header file so you
>   can explore it yourself. While a less general solution can be less
>   complex, you will still need to implement a base class, do the state
>   management, error handling etc. At this moment I can’t go into more
>   detail, but I will say that you will love how easy it is to author
>   async operations with PPL – so hang in there!
>
> Artur Laksberg PPL team

Then, there is no solution at that time. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can do it.  Look at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/10/27/try-it-now-use-ppl-to-produce-windows-8-asynchronous-operations.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-8-Asynchronous-08009a0d

WinRT Async Production using C++

Answer (score 4):

Use [create_async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750102.aspx) in C++:

```
IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer^, unsigned int>^ RandomAccessStream::ReadAsync(IBuffer^ buffer, unsigned int count, InputStreamOptions options)
{
    if (buffer == nullptr)
        throw ref new InvalidArgumentException;

    auto taskProvider = [=](progress_reporter<unsigned int> progress, cancellation_token token)
    {
        return ReadBytesAsync(buffer, count, token, progress, options);
    };
    return create_async(taskProvider);
}
```

Use [AsyncInfo.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.asyncinfo.run.aspx) in .NET:

```
public IAsyncOperation<IInfo> Async()
{
    return AsyncInfo.Run(_ =>
        Task.Run<AType>(async () =>
        {
            return await DoAsync();
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: THere is an await keyword in C++/CX now? And TPL too? :) But this is still a good tip for .NET

Comment: I'm sorry. The language is not specified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see Ben Kuhn's //BUILD/ talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-203T  He shows how to build an asynchronous API.

At the current time, there is no good solution for high level (C++/WX) classes.  However if you use the low level C++ interfaces, you can use the WRL::AsyncBase class to help build your async interfaces.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244878%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) is documentation about the AsyncBase class.

Comment: AFAICS, he shows how to build async interface using the .Net class `AsyncInfoFactory`, that's not available from C++/CX.

Comment: PPL is the long-term solution, obviously that's not an option right now.  But the async APIs are relatively straightforward.  Take a look at wrl\async.h, the WRL::AsyncBase class allows you to create an asynchronous C++ class.  Note that it only works with low level C++ classes, not high level classes, so there may be some challenges getting this to work on the developer preview builds.

Comment: Thank you all. It seems more reasonable though expect MS with some solution and patterns. Even so, I am recurring to this material, but as you can see, they did not encoureged me to follow any path.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing, but there is a difference between WinRT C++ code and WRL.  You can use WRL to code to the ABI layer directly.  WRL does not use exceptions, but loves templates.  The recommend coding style for WinRT is not the same as WRL.

I am not sure if *everyone* can do this, but using WRL you in general need to implement a class that inherits:

```
class CreateAysncOp: public RuntimeClass<IAsyncOperation<result_runtime_class*>,AsyncBase<IAsyncCompletedHandler<result_runtime_class*>>
{
...
```

Then you can use

```
hr = MakeAndInitialize<CreateAsyncOp, IAsyncOperation<type_foo*>>(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ WinRT is now the best way to implement WinRT async methods. This uses `co_await` and `co_return`, new C++ language features (in the process of standardization). Read the docs on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency).